# How can a socket error be addressed when e-mailing in Python from local host (without login to an STMP server)?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm writing a small e-mailing script that is intended to be used by a group of trusted people. After a long job that has been run by one of these people has completed, this script could run and send a simple e-mail with details on the job results. I do not want the script to try to log into an existing e-mail account on an STMP server, I want the e-mail sent simply from the computer on which the script is run.

When I try to run using `localhost`, I encounter a socket error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./1_email.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "./1_email.py", line 34, in main
    server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def main():

    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = "test"
    message["From"]    = "monitor@localhost"
    message["To"]      = "test@sern.ch"

    text = "hello world"
    html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <p>
    hello world
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

    message.attach(part1)
    message.attach(part2)

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
        server.sendmail(
            message["From"],
            message["To"],
            message.as_string()
        )
        server.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print("e-mail send error")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is there an smtp daemon running on port 25 of the localhost?

Comment: @Oli Hey there, thanks for your comment. When I run `telnet localhost 25` I get a message including something like `lxplus0059.sern.ch ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Fri, 11 Mar 2016 16:52:51 +0100`, so I think it is running an accessible via that port.

Comment: Hmm, the socket error is now not observed. The script seems to be running now (though I'm not receiving any e-mails from it).

Comment: ... and now I'm receiving e-mails from it. This was a transient problem with the SMTP server.